# Databricks JDBC Integrated Security

Tags: python-3.x, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

Help :) I need to connect from my Azure databricks cluster to a SQL Azure instance using my Azure AD credentials. I have tested and I can connect to the target database using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) through my Azure AD credentials so that works fine.

Firewall connectivity is fine. I have been able to temporarily test with a SQL username and password and this works fine, but that is about to be taken away from me.

However, connecting through databricks I get:

> om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:

How do I configure the driver? Or possibly use an alternative?

My code below.

Thanks

```
 %python

 jdbcHostname = "<MY>.database.windows.net" jdbcDatabase = "sqldb"
 jdbcPort = 1433 
 jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)

 connectionProperties = {   
     "integratedSecurity" : "true",  
     "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
 }

 print (jdbcUrl)

 pushdown_query = "(select * from nodes) my_nodies" 
 df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties) 

 display(df)
```

Comment: Not possible today. Technically could be implemented, it has been recently for data lake where you can pass through your credentials. But this doesn't exist for sql today. You must use sql authentication.